# JavaScript animated smooth-scroll

Tags: javascript

By default when you have fragment links like this:

```
<a href="/some-url#some-fragment">some text</a>
```

the browser just, scrolls down to that fragment instantly. How do i program it to smoothly move down to that fragment with standard JS?

Here's an example:

[Example](http://www.google.com/intl/en/+/business/get-insights.html) (To see the working example, just click on the 3 arrows inside the 3 circles and watch the smooth animated scrolling)

Comment: You should be using jquery lib or scroll plugins

Comment: @RoyMJ the example i've provided doesn't seem to do so..

Comment: @sid can you show me the line of code that says, that it uses jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay, i think i found my answer, posting it here to help others with the similar doubt:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var singleton = {};
      var timeout = singleton;

      window.onscroll = windowScroll;

      function windowScroll ()
      {
        var toTop = document.getElementById('toTop');
        toTop.style.display = ((window.scrollY > 0) ? "block" : "none");
      }

      function scrollStep ()
      {
        var y1 = window.scrollY - 1000;
        window.scrollTo(0, y1);

        if (y1 > 0)
        {
          timeout = window.setTimeout(scrollStep, 100);  
        }
        else if (timeout != singleton)
        {
          window.clearTimeout(timeout);   
        }
      }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
      #toTop {
        display: block;
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        font-size: 48px;
      }

      #toTop {
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
        opacity: 0.5;
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #toTop:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="top">your text here</p>
    <a href="#top" onclick="scrollStep(); return false" id="toTop"
       ><img src="images/go-to-top.png" alt="Go to top" title="Go to top"></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have made some improvements as to code style, stability, and accessibility.  The transition may not have worked/may not work, though, because it is not applied to elements with `display: none`.  To work around that, you would probably have to use `opacity` all the time and have a delayed transition for the `height` property.

Answer (score 0):

Well you should try something like this

```
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop:$("#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Conten
tPlaceHolder1_txtcomment").offset().top
},'slow');
```

where ***#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtcomment*** is the id where you want to move or scroll

another approch is to put this in a function

```
function scrollme() {
$('html,body').animate({
scrollTop:$("#ctl00_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtcomment").offset().top
},'slow');
} <a onclick="javascript:scrollme();">some text</a>
```

I hope this will help you.

Regards..:)

**[Updated]**

> A URI hash is a great way to make JavaScript/AJAX pages with dynamic
>   content bookmarkable. It can be used in a manner similar to query
>   strings, but changes will not cause a new page request. This allows
>   you to store data in the URI which can be read and changed by
>   JavaScript without ever reloading the page.
>
> For the uninitiated, a URI location hash is everything after the #
>   sign in the URI:
>
> http://domain.com/page.html#i-am-a-hash A side note: URI hashes are
>   not transferred back to the server, you can only access them
>   client-side.

check this blog

http://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/using-uri-hash-instead-of-query-strings/

Comment: i know i can do that. my doubt is how does the example do that?

it doesn't say, href="javascript:something()" it says href="#some-fragment"

Comment: and i want to use standard javascript

Comment: this not not standard JS. this is jquery